# DevExpress select text range within a TextEdit repositoryItem cell of a GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

Does anybody know how to select a text range within a TextEdit repositoryItem cell of a GridControl?

The the following code it select the whole text of the cell:

```
gvMemoryMap.FocusedRowHandle = 4;
gvMemoryMap.FocusedColumn = gvMemoryMap.VisibleColumns[1];
gvMemoryMap.ShowEditor();
gvMemoryMap.ActiveEditor.SelectAll();
```

But I would like to select a text range as well as someTextBox.Select(2,5) does in the Winforms control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got [DevExpress thread](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q273875.aspx) that meet same requirement as you do. Check the modified code as per your requirement and follow the following approach.

Cast your `ActiveEditor` to `DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit` and you are able to work as you do on `TextEdit Control`.

```
gvMemoryMap.FocusedRowHandle = 4;
gvMemoryMap.FocusedColumn = gvMemoryMap.VisibleColumns[1];
gvMemoryMap.ShowEditor();
(gvMemoryMap.ActiveEditor as DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit).Select(0, 1);
```

It is tested and working.. Hope this help..

Comment: Thanks! believe me when I say that I searched a lot without success and obviously without matching that thread.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following approach:

```
TextEdit textEdit = gvMemoryMap.ActiveEditor as TextEdit;
textEdit.Select(2, 3);
```

Related help topic: [TextEdit.Select(Int32,Int32) Method](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTextEdit_Selecttopic459)